# How do I link my JavaScript function to an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my randomly generated number to appear in a paragraph in my `HTML` but I keep getting an `error` that I cannot set text content of `null`. The id is correct and where I would like it to be. What am I doing incorrectly?

```js
function generateNumToMatch() {
    var numToMatch = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) + 1));
    document.getElementById("computerNumber").textContent = numToMatch;
}
```

```html
 <div class ="card-body">
    <p id ="computerNumber" class="card-text"></p>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: Post your code. It's hard to debug images.

Comment: Your problem cannot be reproduced given the posted code. Please make a [MCVE] that can illustrate the problem.

Comment: Do those elements exist on page load? I cannot reproduce this either: http://jsfiddle.net/a5m6s0op/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in the JS, I was able to produce random numbers using this:

```
var numToMatch;
generateNumToMatch();
function generateNumToMatch() {
    numToMatch = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) + 1));
}
document.getElementById("computerNumber").textContent = numToMatch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML element needs to use the onclick attribute.  Add a button, and add code to it like this:

```
<button onclick="generateNumToMatch()">Click me</button>
```

The button's onClick event fires which runs your javascript code.  Your javascript code will run and set the element called "computerNumber" text property to the random number you created.

Alternatively, you can run the code once, so you do it like this:

```
var numToMatch;
numToMatch = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) + 1));
document.getElementById("computerNumber").textContent = numToMatch;
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggered by an `onclick` event:

```js
function generateNumToMatch() {
    let numToMatch = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) + 1));
    document.getElementById("computerNumber").innerHTML = numToMatch;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <button onclick="generateNumToMatch()">Get a number</button>
        <p id="computerNumber"></p>
 </div>
```

Triggered on a page load:

```js
function generateNumToMatch() {
    let numToMatch = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (100) + 1));
    document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = numToMatch;
}
```

```css
span {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<body onload="generateNumToMatch()">
  <h4>Random number goes here: 
    <span id="num"></span>
  </h4>
</body>
```